# Why does my Fortify Restoration potion also improve Enchanting and Alchemy?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Why does a Fortify Restoration potion also augment seemingly unrelated skills that aren't mentioned in the name?

Comment: Are you talking about a potion you concocted? Those potions will include buffs applied by each ingredient.

Comment: Also, can you stop asking 7 questions at once? This isn't a blog for your ramblings.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer There's a [meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12176/145980) about this user's frequent posting. The consensus appears to be that asking many questions in a short amount of time is not necessarily a problem. The real problem is that the questions are not very good. Just downvote and move on; the system will eventually ban him if he does not increase the quality of his questions.

Comment: @MageXy Asking 5 different questions in a single post is a problem, and what I was referring to.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Oh, I see the edit history now. Yeah, Jim really needs to work on making his question clearer and not so rambly.

Comment: The 5 questions are related and help explains the main question

Comment: @JimThio, seriously, they don't. Stop adding to the question. I edited your question to the barebones question you really seemed to be asking. Don't flood the question body with a bunch of speculation that obscures the real question being asked.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is multi-faceted but most likely due to a mixture of UI decisions.

Easily found, is the [Fandom Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Created_Potions_(Skyrim)) regarding Skyrim potions. If you research this page you find that potions and ingredients have up to four effects. This is also experienced in playing when eating ingredients and learning one of its effects each time.

How this may be a UI decision is the space taken to display effects beyond secondary takes much visual real-estate wherefore many players want to get the basic info and move on.

Additionally, players who are interested in deep lore to include alchemic properties will likely take their own notes (The fandom Wikia lends credit to this in that it exists from player input and collected notes.)

There are at least four other first and second page search results on potions and what happens when, why, and how within Skyrim.

Please also note this is an answer to the main title and body question, not the OP self-answered theory.

Comment: I am aware that potion have secondary property. I don't think this is the issue though. Fortify restoration by itself, always improves other fortify skills.

Comment: What you are saying is that fortify restoration may have other effect, say fortify archery. That's not the issue. Fortify restoration itself improves other fortify skills.

Comment: Yes, but also tertiary properties. Fortify Restoration also specifically changes depending on ingredients. I suggest you read through the link carefully as I'm helping you, not doing it for you.

Comment: I read that. Sometimes fortify restoration have secondary properties like fortify enchanting. I want to know if fortify restoration by it self, increase the effect of fortify alchemy gears. The answer seems to be yes

Comment: (1)You're wanting to know something other than what you've asked in a manner that isn't merely progression of thought or working to a solution for question you asked. Point in case - the answer seems to be "yes" to what? Your main question wasn't close-ended (yes/no) and (2) Using the comments to reshape and ask additional questions under the guise of dissatisfaction with the numerous resources given for you to get your answer, definitively, is noted. I'm not going to engage with assisting you on this anymore. The resources I used to answer your question are there. Use them or don't.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't; it's just a bug related to how buff potions behave.

Comment: This answer would be improved by backup from a citation/link to an explanation of the bug.

Answer (score -2):

Based on answer here
[What is the Math Formula on Fortify Restoration Potion Improves Fortify Other Skills](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/295975/what-is-the-math-formula-on-fortify-restoration-potion-improves-fortify-other-sk/296185#296185)

The way it works is that **fortify X counts** as a **restoration effect.**

That is exactly the problem.

Also equipping fortify X is seen as applying a restoration effect that is improved by fortify restoration alchemy.

So no, it's not a bug. It's the way it's supposed to work.

I saw this post

http://skyrimforums.org/sf/threads/infinite-fortify-restoration-exploit.3116/

The way I understand it, is the following.

It has something to do with removing clothes and putting them back on again.

If that's true, that explains why the PC have to put off the clothes and put it back again. Just drinking fortify restoration while wearing the clothes won't work.

That is, the effect of fortify alchemy must **be added while** the user is under the effect of fortify restoration.

The fortify restoration does not improves alchemy or enchanting directly. Drinking fortify restoration and then putting fortify alchemy causes it.

In other words, it's not a bug. The fortify restoration works as intended, magnifying the beneficial effect.

Comment: First, you're answering your own question which negates the purpose of asking the initial question. Second, exp

Comment: ...Sorry thumb hit button on phone. Second, explaining your theory doesn't necessarily justify the circular rambling.

Comment: @ShawnGordon stackexchange sites accept answering your own question as it adds to the overall body of knowledge on the site. see http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/etiquette-of-immediately-answering-ones-own-question

Comment: Ah, fair enough.

Comment: My answer after my own research may be more correct than the upvoted answer. It's not just a bug. There is a reasoning behind it that may be true. It may not be true but that's the best I can come up with

Comment: And I did the research AFTER I asked the question. I thought this was an easy question where everyone that have touched a computer knows the answer on top of their head except me. Turns out no body knows why.

Comment: "In other words, it's not a bug." Except it absolutely is.

Comment: @Arkive Yes, we allow self answers, but all that's here is speculation and random guessing.  There's nothing here except jumping to conclusions and reaching to justify how it works.

Comment: @Jim Thio,  you did research AFTER you asked a question you assumed everyone would know the answer to, except you. Help me understand how that logic process makes sense.

Comment: It seems that this is not a simple question.

Comment: My point was that people generally do research BEFORE they ask a question, ESPECIALLY if they "assume" everyone who's touched it would know. The latter is relatively true - I can search on at least four different sites and the answer I gave is what you'll find. Your issue isn't a lack of answer, it's a lack of accepting the answers which exist because they aren't what you want to hear. I can't change that, man. It is what it is.